# How to automatically run a.out file at the startup in Pi board?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, startup

I have an executable file a.out and I want to run it every time when my Pi board boots up? any suggestions how I can do it?

Comment: Also, rename a.out to something meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` says:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
```

Also, did you know about this board: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Create a new shell script in /etc/init.d containing the path to your app:

```
#!/bin/sh
/<insertpath>/a.out
```

Tell the system to update its startup:

```
update-rc.d a.out defaults
```

Finally you need to make your app executable:

```
chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/a.out
```